# vscode. Outer context while editing inner source code

Tags: visual-studio-code, editing

In Visual studio code, language javascript/typescript in my case, when you are deep in code, for example in the implementation of a method, I miss some quick way to know the context where I am (ie. at least the class where I am).

I suspect I'm missing something but so far I haven't found a way to know at a glance what's the outer context, an extension perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VScode's [July 2018 release introduces "Breadcrumbs"](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_breadcrumbs) that do it beautifully